# Can I just open the terminal in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Well, the terminal theme in vscode is better than Windows default terminal(PowerShell also).

Can I just open the terminal part but not the entire vscode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, the terminal is integrated directly with vscode. You can use a vscode window and just make the terminal as big as the window itself.

Similar question on superuser: 
https://superuser.com/questions/1468225/is-it-possible-to-detach-the-terminal-window-from-vscode